# Сохранение GET параметра, после отправки формы

Tags: php

Делаю калькулятор, в котором примеры берутся из json файла, а json файл выбирается GET параметром.

Если написать **?test=1** то данные берутся из файла **test1.json**
а если написать **?test=2** то данные берутся из файла **test2.json**

Но после того, как отправить форму, то получается передаётся параметр **sum** и переменная **$answer** стирается, получается, мне надо сохранить 2 параметра get, как это можно сделать?

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

if(isset($_GET['test'])){
    $getParametr = true;
    $file = file_get_contents('test/test' . $_GET['test'] . '.json', true);
    $decode = json_decode($file, true);

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($decode);
    echo '</pre>';

    $primer = $decode["calculate"]["description"];
    $answer = $decode["calculate"]["result"];

    echo $answer;

}

else{
    $getParametr = false;
}

if(isset($_GET['sum']) == $answer){
    echo 'Правильный ответ';        
}

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Генератор тестов</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="get">
        <label for="sum">

        <?php if($getParametr) {
                echo $decode["calculate"]["description"];
            } 
            else echo '1 + 1';
        ?>
        </label>

        <input type="text" name="sum" id="sum">

        <input type="submit" value="Проверить">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**json файл**

```
{
    "calculate" : {
        "description" : "2+2?=",
        "input" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "name" : "number1"
        },
        "result" : 4
    }
}
```

Comment: ну вообще в get берется из адресной строки, а туда вы хоть массивы можете пихать, вот пример двух переменных index.php?test=1&sum=10

Comment: изучите функции http://php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php и http://php.net/manual/ru/function.http-build-query.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как вариант:
изменить у формы метод отправки на POST

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

также изменить

```
if(isset($_GET['sum']) == $answer){
```

на

```
if(isset($_POST['sum']) == $_POST['answer']){
```

добавить в форму

```
<input type="hidden" name="answer" value="<?php echo $answer; ?>">
```

но в этом случае, если посмотреть на исходный код страницы, то буден виден ответ.

2 вариант, можно сохранить переменную в сессии
в начало скрипта добавить

```
session_start();
```

заменить

```
$answer = $decode["calculate"]["result"];
```

на

```
$_SESSION['answer'] = $decode["calculate"]["result"];
```

удалить

```
echo $answer;
```

изменить

```
if(isset($_GET['sum']) == $answer){
```

на

```
if(isset($_GET['sum']) == $_SESSION['answer']){
```